# Hangfire: run method with scoped service injected

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, hangfire

I am enqueuing a Hangfire job in a web-api controller action but I need a service to be injected for the task.

This is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public string DoSomething() => _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<MyStorageService>(s => EnqueueJob(s));

[JobDisplayName("My job"), DisableConcurrentExecution(10 * 60)]
private static async void EnqueueJob(MyStorageService myservice)
{
    await myservice.DoAsync();
}
```

However, `MyStorageService` seems to capture some context that is missing, because I get following exception.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: variable 's' of type 'MyStorageService' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
         at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile()
         at Hangfire.Common.ExpressionUtil.CachedExpressionCompiler.Compiler`2.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CompileFromFingerprint>b__0(ExpressionFingerprintChain _)
         at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
         at Hangfire.Common.ExpressionUtil.CachedExpressionCompiler.Compiler`2.CompileFromFingerprint(Expression`1 expr)
         at Hangfire.Common.ExpressionUtil.CachedExpressionCompiler.Compiler`2.Compile(Expression`1 expr)
         at Hangfire.Common.ExpressionUtil.CachedExpressionCompiler.Process[TModel,TValue](Expression`1 lambdaExpression)
         at Hangfire.Common.CachedExpressionCompiler.Wrap(Expression arg)
         at Hangfire.Common.CachedExpressionCompiler.Evaluate(Expression arg)
         at Hangfire.Common.Job.GetExpressionValue(Expression expression)
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
```

`MyStorageService` uses Entity Framework / DbContext to run queries.

**Update 1:**

`MyStorageService` is added as scoped service in `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyStorageService>();
```

**Update 2:**

I tried to apply the .net 7 documentation to my service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Which injects an `IServiceProvider serviceProvider` to explicitly create a scope. This changes the code to:

```
[HttpPost]
public string ImportAsync()
{
    using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var scopedProcessingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyStorageService>();
    return _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => EnqueueJob(scopedProcessingService));
}

[JobDisplayName("My job"), DisableConcurrentExecution(10 * 60)]
public static async Task EnqueueJob(MyStorageService myservice)
{
    await myservice.DoAsync();
}
```

This allows to call the `DoAsync()` method now, however some dependencies seem not to be injected inside of MyStorageService, because some object are now (only in this context) `not set to an instance of an object`.

Error:

```
Failed to process the job '3': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 1 of 10 will be performed in 00:00:44.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at ..MyStorageService.DoAsync() in ..\MyStorageService.cs:line 52
at ..MyController.Enqueue(MyStorageService myservice) in ..MyController.cs:line 67
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
...
```

Comment: Can you post what is on line: `MyStorageService.cs:line 52` ?
Because there is an object there, which is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection in Hangfire works only for the target of the method call.
You should refactor your code like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public string DoSomething() => _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<MyStorageService>(s => s.EnqueueJob());
```

Where `EnqueueJob`is an instance method of class `MyStorageService`.  ([Avoid using `async void` methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void))

```
[JobDisplayName("My job"), DisableConcurrentExecution(10 * 60)]
public async Task EnqueueJob()
{
    await this.DoAsync();
}
```